# Java PreparedStatement SQL Syntax for LIKE

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a prepared statement as so:

```
private static final String SQL_LIST_GROUP = "SELECT * 
                                                FROM table 
                                               WHERE group LIKE ?;"
```

My function, my function is as follow(shortened and SQL objects properly declared):

```
public List< MyType > getGroupList(Long grp) {  
   Connection link = null;  
    PreparedStatement query = null;    
    ResultSet rstList = null;  
    List< MyType > list = new ArrayList< MyType >();  
    try {  
        link = MySQL.getConnection();    
        link.setAutoCommit(false);  
        query = link.prepareStatement(SQL_LIST_GROUP);  
        query.setString(1, "%"+grp.toString()+",%");  
        rstList = query.executeQuery();  
        link.commit();  
        while (rstList.next()) {  
            list.add(MapFields(rstList));  
        }  
        return list;  
    } catch (SQLException e) {  
        throw new DAOException(e);  
    } finally {  
        close(link, query, rstList);  
    }  
}
```

The conections are made properly, but I get a syntax error, the prepared statement with the value parsed is as follows:

```
"SELECT * 
   FROM table 
  WHERE group LIKE '%grp%';"
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: thnks for editing the inline, I tried the 4 spaces but it didn't work..

Comment: Are you sure there should be a comma in +",%"

Comment: yes, it is an integer separated list:  
1,3,56,7,8,6,5,6

Comment: Can you add the actual error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also seen issues with semi-colons in PreparedStatemts.

Also, the parameter to the method is called 'grp', but 'group' is being used in the call to setString.  Is that a type-o, or part of the problem?   group.toString() should suffice, no need for the valueOf/longValue stuff.

Another thing, 'group' is a reserved word in MySQL.

Comment: Yeah, thats a typo, will correct it right away.. I've never thought of the toString() method, great contribution also I didn't know that 'group' was a reserved word, I'll change the field thanks.

Comment: Renamed the field from 'group' to 'guild', that solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a DB bomb out because of a trailing ; in dynamic SQL before. Does removing that cause it to work?

Comment: the semi-colon doesn't affect at all, I've tried it in MySQL WorkBench with no problems, actually I like using it.

Comment: Good to know. I believe in Oracle and DB2 it is an issue. Sorry my answer did not solve your issue.